# SQLITE: Single table with 20 columns vs 20 key-value tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, key-value-store

I'm developing system that manages objects consisting of components. **What would the best way to store them in SQLITE database from performance point of view?** if there are 20 component types
each component is a blob 1-10Kb size. Typically each object consists of 4-6 different components.

I can see two options:

1. Implement it as one table with key and 20 blob columns
2. Use 20 tables with key and single blob column

The only queries I will make to database are: get component data by id, write data and remove data.

PS: object class looks like this:

```
class Entity
{
    Component *components[20];
}
```

usually components array have 4-6 not null pointers

Comment: 1) Easiest way to find out is to benchmark both **for your workload**. 
2) When benchmarking make sure you know how much you care about latency vs throughput.  3) Performance questions are almost always workload-specific.

Comment: Yeah, but I think my question is more about sqlite and the way it stores multiple fields internally. Will it be efficent if 75% of values in columns are empty?

Comment: In that case, you should probably a) Rephrase your question to ask about sqlite storage structure and perhaps b) demonstrate effort by pointing at the place in the source code where you looked and did not understand.

Comment: I think the answer is obvously depends only on sqlite internals. And I ask this question because in order to answer it either needs a enormous effort to analyze sqlite sources or large experience working with sqlite databases

Comment: Let me try to paraphrase, is this right?  You have Objects that each contain a Set of Components.  There are *exactly* 20 different possible ComponentType.  *(When you say "ComponentType", does that mean that there are multiple Different Components that are all ComponentType1?  If so, is each Object's version of ComponentType1 different from every other Object's version of ComponentType1?)*  Each Object can optionally have either Zero or One of each of the 20 ComponentTypes, and this number 20 is fixed and will never change?  If you could express this as Classes, and give examples, that helps.

Comment: MatBailie, yeah you are absolutely right!

Comment: ***(When you say "ComponentType", does that mean that there are multiple Different Components that are all ComponentType1? If so, is each Object's version of ComponentType1 different from every other Object's version of ComponentType1?)***

Comment: 1)there is only one component for each type 2)yes, each component data is unique

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want an Entity Attribute Value structure to store the BLOBs.

```
CREATE TABLE myObjectComponents (
   objectID          INTEGER,    -- Entity
   componentTypeID   INTEGER,    -- Attribute
   componentBLOB     BLOB,       -- Value
   PRIMARY KEY objectID, componentTypeID
)
```

You can then also add a traditional "myObject" table with other non-blob values *(Such as it's identity column, owner, name, creation and modified timestamps, etc, etc)*, and enforce integrity with foreign key constraints.

EAV tables are very flexible and good for fast look-up of the Value column.

They're very poor in the other direction; "given a Value *(or combination of values)*, which Entities have it?"  But you don't seem likely to be searching a BLOB field.

You may want to read more about the merits and dis-advantages of EAV, there are plenty of references on-line.

The benefit of this structure in your case is that each row only has one BLOB and *(possibly more importantly)* it isn't sparsely populated; You won't have rows with capacity for 20 BLOBs but only use, for example, four of those.  This will make it easier to transfer the relevant rows around in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But do you think EAV is better than separate table for each type? With separate tables I will have faster and smaller indexes and so they should operate faster.

Comment: I'd need to know more about your application, but in general that would be considered premature optimisation.  20 tables reduces flexibility and only has very marginal benefit in the indexes.  In purely simplistic terms, your suggestion can result in needing to execute 20 statements against 20 different tables *(requiring 20 slightly different statements)*, where as the single table would accomplish this in one query - one index seek.  In over 10 years of DB work I've always found that fewer tables (*within reason*) results in shorter, more maintainable/flexible, and often faster code.

Comment: You may benefit in writing out all of your use cases to understand what sql statements you're going to be executing.  You may find that you're often running several queries against your 20-table structure (or worse, joining them all together), compared to a single query against the EAV table.  You can then estimate the performance benefit you'd need on each individual query to alleviate the overhead of running more queries.  It's hard to imagine any case where your gains will be more than your additional overheads.

Comment: Really the only important use case is getting component data by its type and id - because component data randomly loaded on demand. All my structure I have in memory (not in database) and only huge components loaded from database as needed

Comment: I would still recommend EAV.